# How should I split my data for cross validation and grid search?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, cross-validation, grid-search

Should i split my data in to two parts similar in size to use each half for eaxh tasks or i should do grid search on my whole data and then just do cross validation again on my whole data to check my accuracy ?

Comment: Caution: If your dataset is time series, you might want to split it sequentially, as opposed to random splitting.

Comment: This is not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; questions on ML theory and methodology should be addressed to [Cross Validated](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (although I guess it is too vague & broad even for them)

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the data into test and train (20:80) (eg. **test_train_split** in sklearn), then run the model with the train data and check the accuracy. If its not what you expect, then you can try applying Hyper parameter Tuning.

You can do this by GridSearchCV, where you need to fit the desired estimator (depending on the type of problem ) and the parameter values.

Attached a sample code :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
# Create the parameter grid based on the results of random search 
param_grid = {
    'bootstrap': [True],
    'max_depth': [50, 55, 60, 65],
    'max_features': ["auto","sqrt", 2, 3],
    'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 3],
    'min_samples_split': [2, 3, 4],
    'n_estimators': [60, 65, 70, 75]
}


grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = rfcv, param_grid = param_grid, cv = 3, n_jobs = -1, verbose = 2)

grid_search.fit(X_train, Y_train)
grid_search.best_params_
```

Based the best parameter results, you can fine tune the grid search.

Eg, if best parameter value is near 60 for n_estimators then you need to change the values as surrounding to 60 like [50,55,60,60]. To figure out the exact value.

Then build the machine learning model based on the best parameters value. Evaluate the train data accuracy and then predict the result using test data values.

```
rf = rgf(n_estimators = 70, random_state=0, min_samples_split = 2, min_samples_leaf=1, max_features = 'sqrt',bootstrap='True', max_depth=65)
regressor = rf.fit(X_train,Y_train)
pred_tuned = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

You can find an improvement in your accuracy !!